# What does it mean in C++ when using brackets after a type name?

Tags: c++

I am really confused about the following piece of C++ code:

```
// The global task manager
PT(AsyncTaskManager) taskMgr = AsyncTaskManager::get_global_ptr(); 
// The global clock
PT(ClockObject) globalClock = ClockObject::get_global_clock();
```

Is 'PT' a type name? And why there are brackets after it? I`ve never seen such kind of syntax in C++(may be I should read some C++ tutorials again?)

Comment: looks like #define trick but there may be compiler hints too. Define macro is very good when there are lots of parameters to give to functions, you give just a single word instead of 20 parameters

Comment: Looks like a macro `#define PT(x) x*` for me.

Comment: Oh yeah, that must be a macro definition.

Comment: Ugly Useless Macro of the day.

Comment: Which got me confused absolutely

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Using macros is usually a bad idea. If you have functions that take _that_ many parameters using macros just hides a bigger problem.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: Even if you have a function with 20 parameters, which is already bad as it is, why write a macro and not just use a wrapper function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My second Google hit for *"c++ AsyncTaskManager"* (the first is your question here) is:

http://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5115

Which in turn leads to http://www.panda3d.org/, where it says:

> Panda3D is a game engine, a framework for 3D rendering and game
>   development for Python and C++ programs.

So you are apparently dealing with a piece of code related to that engine (which I had not heard of myself before). Browsing the documentation online does not quickly reveal any definition for `PT`, but if you download the source code and just search all files for *"#define PT"*, voilà:

File `pointerTo.h`, from line 166 onward:

```
// Finally, we'll define a couple of handy abbreviations to save on
// all that wasted typing time.

#define PT(type) PointerTo< type >
```

If you investigate further, you will see that `PointerTo` is actually quite a complicated template class, documented as:

> PointerTo is a template class which implements a smart pointer to an
>   object derived from ReferenceCount.

So `PT(AsyncTaskManager) taskMgr = AsyncTaskManager::get_global_ptr();` is really:

```
PointerTo<AsyncTaskManager> taskMgr = AsyncTaskManager::get_global_ptr();
```

---

If I my say so, I think that all the *"wasted typing time"* supposedly saved by the macro is easily consumed by all the reading and research time required to understand the code. As evidenced by this whole question and all comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's to save typing effort. It's so much easier to type `PT(AsyncTaskManager)` than `AsyncTaskManager*`. You can also do stuff like:

```
#define BEGIN {
#define END }
```

Comment: _"It's to save typing effort."_ Uhm what? Not if it's for simple pointers, `AsyncTaskManager*` is even three characters less.

Comment: Or my personal favorite: `#define IF(x) if(x)`.